# Duplicate instances of records flooding my Access report

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm having a duplication issue that I just can't figure out. Basically my report & subreport are pulling a previous contributor list. What I need is for each instance of paid history to be grouped by the phone number and then the whole shebang sorted by date of the last sale. This is mostly happening except the problem is that for every instance of the sale, I am getting the full info returned. This is causing a lot of duplicates as you can imagine with the 10,000+ customers we have.

So to be clear, in my example below I am getting the full phone number, name/address, and both sales in both places (based on date) in my report. I will see all of the info on both 1/4/2013 AND 6/6/2012. I don't want or need the instance at 6/6/2012 to show up, I only want it to show up alongside the 1/4/2013 sales. It still needs to have the 6/6/2012 paid history there, I just need the 2nd instance of it all to be eradicated.

```
555-1212
john smith
123 whatever dr
hometown, usa 90210

sold date   received date   amount   agentname
1/1/2013       1/4/2013       50       jack
6/1/2012       6/6/2012       25       jim


555-1212
john smith
123 whatever dr
hometown, usa 90210

sold date   received date   amount   agentname
1/1/2013       1/4/2013       50       jack
6/1/2012       6/6/2012       25       jim
```

My report is setup so the phone number, name, and address are all inside the PhoneNumber header and my subreport which contains the sold/received dates, amount, and agentnames is inside the detail section.

Here's the query for my main report:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    tblContributorsLead.PhoneNumber, tblContributorsLead.FirstName, 
    tblContributorsLead.LastName, tblContributorsLead.Address1, 
    tblContributorsLead.ZipCode, tblContributorsLead.CityName, 
    tblPledgesLead.PledgeAmountRecd, tblPledgesLead.DateRecd
FROM 
    tblContributorsLead 
    INNER JOIN tblPledgesLead 
        ON tblContributorsLead.PhoneNumber = tblPledgesLead.PhoneNumber
WHERE 
    (((tblPledgesLead.PledgeAmountRecd)>0) 
    AND ((tblPledgesLead.DateRecd) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY 
    tblPledgesLead.DateRecd DESC;
```

Here's the query for my subreport:

```
SELECT 
    tblPledgesLead.PhoneNumber, tblPledgesLead.DispositionTime, 
    tblPledgesLead.DateRecd, tblPledgesLead.PledgeAmountRecd, 
    tblPledgesLead.Agent, tblPledgesLead.CampaignName, 
    tblPledgesLead.Custom20
FROM 
    tblPledgesLead
WHERE 
    (((tblPledgesLead.PledgeAmountRecd)>0));
```

I'd also like to say that this system was already in place before I took control, and I'm relatively new with access so any help will be greatly appreciated. I've moved every piece of this thing into and out of every section I can see and have tried a multitude of grouping and sorting options but to no avail.

edit: here's a couple screenshots showing the issue. In the first screenshot I have circled a particular contributor. Notice the Date Rec'd column on each sale, that is the date they are being sorted by. The place that this contributor is at currently is where it should be, alongside the other sales from 9/23/2013. In the second screenshot you can see her full info listed again at the location of her previous sale, on 12/14/2010. This continues on for each and every date she has ever paid. This sale in particular will have 4 copies instead of just the one that I need. The one that I need should look identical to the one from 9/23/2013, containing all prior sale info alongside.

First:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzf3n.jpg

Second:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/43DQP.jpg

Comment: Can you edit this question and attach a screenshot of your report to it?  As it stands, I don't understand what it is that you **don't** want to see.

Comment: Well I'm not sure that a screenshot would help much more than what I've already posted above. Basically at every date in which there is a collected pledge for a customer, the entire block of info is duplicated. So if someone gives in march, july, and december i will see three full copies of his donation history (including all 3 of those paid dates). What I need is for it to ONLY show me the record alongside the sales in december since that would be the most recent sale. The record in december should also list the sales from march and july alongside, but in march and july I should see nothing.

Comment: Currently if I go to march or july I will see more copies of the same contributor including their history. This is essentially giving me 3 copies of the same contributor lead, which is a nightmare. I just need a single record showing all their payment history and it all needs to be grouped on the phone number and in sorted in order of most recent payment first. I'll go ahead and edit in a screenshot in a minute here.

Comment: Joins are normally done on a Primary Key and corresponding Foreign Key in the child table. Is Phone Number a primary key in your Contributors table and a Foreign Key in your Pledges table?

Comment: Correct. PhoneNumber is my primary key in tblContributorsLead and when I click on Relationships it is linked to PhoneNumber in tblPledgesLead (which is not a primary key there).

Comment: Change DISTINCTROW to DISTINCT. DISTINCTROW matches distinct combinations of all joined data across all tables. Thus if for a row in the ContributorsLead table, there are two matching entries in the PledgesLead table, you get the columns selected from the contributors table twice - which is what you've got. DISTINCT only examines the columns you are reporting, and thus is what you require in this instance.

Comment: I changed it from DISTINCTROW to DISTINCT but I still have the same thing happening.

Comment: I had another look; Your main report is collecting the values tblPledgesLead.PledgeAmountRecd, tblPledgesLead.DateRecd, but there doesnt seem to be any use of these items in the output you're showing. I would expect these values to differ between the first and second instances you are seeing. Are you using them, though you havent shown them in your outputs? If you're not using them, remove them from the select list and try it again (with DISTINCT).

Comment: Yeah those are in use. The PledgeAmountRecd is set to >0 so that our empty records don't get pulled (we have some that have name and address info in the contributor's list but have no sale history, purposefully though). The DateRecd I added in so that I could sort them the right way. I couldn't get them to sort overall by the most recent sale date without having that there. Is that not the right way to go about it?

When I remove those 2 from the query and run it again, it pulls empty sets and It sorts the list by phone number.

Comment: Are the data types for the phone number columns identical? I am suspicious that there is some sort of implicit conversion going on that is converting the fields to a different datatype (such as from string to numeric), making them identical. Try changing the join to read `INNER JOIN tblPledgesLead 
        ON tblContributorsLead.PhoneNumber Like tblPledgesLead.PhoneNumber`

Comment: Looking at the two tables, they are both set as Text fields, the only differences being the field size, the one in Contributors has Format set as "@" while the other has no format listed. The only other difference is duplicates are not allowed in Contributors while they are allowed in Pledges, but that's how they should be since we're allowing multiple Pledges but only want to keep a single Contributor listing per phone number.

When I replace my join to that one, the query won't run. It sits on 1% of Running Query and never progresses.

Comment: Any more ideas on this?